# Adding subview to scroll view hangs my screen

Tags: ios

I have added a scrollview to view using xib auto layout on which i have placed uiswitch. If I select the UISwitch am adding a label and textfield to scrollview programmatically  which hangs my screen and am not able to perform any action.This bug occurs in iPhone5s ..Its working fine iPhone 4 and iPad

```
_hosStartDateLbl.frame=CGRectMake(_birthLbl.frame.origin.x, _birthLbl.frame.origin.y+_birthLbl.frame.size.height+15,  [_hosStartDateLbl.text sizeWithFont:_hosStartDateLbl.font].width, 17);//birthLbl is in xib

[_hosStartDateLbl sizeToFit];

  _hosStartDateTxt.frame=CGRectMake(_hosStartDateLbl.frame.origin.x, _hosStartDateLbl.frame.origin.y+_hosStartDateLbl.frame.size.height+5, eventStartTxt.frame.size.width,eventStartTxt.frame.size.height);//eventStartTxt in xib

[self.scroll addSubview:_hosStartDateLbl];
            _hosStartDateTxt.delegate=self;
[self.scroll addSubview:_hosStartDateTxt];

 scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroll.frame.size.width, _hosStartDateTxt.frame.origin.y+_hosStartDateTxt.frame.size.height+160);
```

Comment: Could you check your scrollView contentSize after adding in the subviews ? Scrollview only scrolls if the subview contents within the scrollView is taller than the scrollView's frame.

Comment: Check ContentSize and autolayaut.

Comment: scroll.contentSize.height am getting 1043.500000
 _hosStartDateLbl.frame.origin.y am getting 761.000000

Comment: my whole screen is getting hanged and after sometime i get a pop up saying "Message from debugger terminated due to memory error"